# copy files from one directory to another based upon similarly named files in a source location

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following structure:

```
SomeDirectory
|   batchfile.bat
|
+---code
|      123456.jpg
|      456789.jpg
|
+---found
\---site
       123456_sabxxx.jpg
       156948_utsnt.jpg
```

For every file in `\code`, I need to copy from `\site`, the file which starts with the same basename, *(but with the `_xxxxxx.jpg` suffixed)*, to `\found`.

I'm stuck here:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (code\*) do (
    set code=%%~nA
    echo file found !code!
    for %%B in (site\*) do (
        if %%~nB = %%~nA*.* (
            xcopy %%B found\
            )
            else () 
        )
    )
echo Finished
pause
```

The batch file is invoked by double-clicking it in the GUI.

Comment: Your `if` syntax is wrong. But you don't need it anyway: Instead of your inner `for` loop: `xcopy "site\%%~nA*" "found\"`

Comment: thanks Stephan, it works, and it's simplier than my solution

Comment: you are right. Now i'm trying to make it as simple as possibile, so it just works with double click mantaining the dir structure. Thanks for your help and your time

Comment: Why take the risk, just fix your code to either define the current directory, or expand the path(s) you're using, by utilising the special metavariable, %0 and its modifiers. As your comment has clarified the structure, and you have not edited your question to make it clear for everyone, I've done that for you.